# How to update a trigger when a row is inserted?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this challenge:

> Create a trigger that sets the column *id* to the value of the *age*
>   column whenever a row is inserted that has id set to NULL.

The query that will be run to check if the trigger works is:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, id, age) VALUES ('Mick', NULL, 632), ('Nick', 52197, 12415550196); SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name IN ('Mick', 'Nick').
```

Sooo, what I did is this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER randomtriggername
AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.id > OLD.id BEGIN
UPDATE ???
END
```

How can I go about the `UPDATE` part? I don't get how to do that. How should I start and what should I do precisely? I'd like to have some directions, as I find the question a bit vague...

Comment: why not this way `... 
before INSERT ...
WHEN age is null BEGIN
 id = age
END

Comment: So you mean like:

CREATE TRIGGER randomtriggername
AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
WHEN age is null BEGIN id = age END

or not?

Comment: I think *BEFORE* . Yuo already know that age is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need an `update` statement, just use `set NEW.id=...` format:

```
CREATE TRIGGER randomtriggername
BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.id=COALESCE(NEW.id, NEW.age);
```

I would use a before trigger and use `coalesce()` function to return the first non-null value.

Comment: Is there a substitution for coalesce? I am trying to avoid IF statements and the coalesce() function.

Comment: Ifnull() function can be used in place of coalesce(). However, it would have been nice to provide these limits in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of a value to a column should be performed in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, not an `AFTER` trigger.  (Don't use an `UPDATE` statement. Just assign a value to the column *before* the row is inserted.)

And if this is for MySQL DBMS (as indicated by the [mysql] tag on the question...

I don't believe MySQL supports the `WHEN` clause on the trigger definition (like some other databases do.)

Something like this would create a trigger to perform the specified operation when a row is inserted to table1: if the value for the `id` column is null, then set the `id` column to the value of the `age` column:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER table1_bi 
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.id IS NULL) THEN
     SET NEW.id = NEW.age;
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Also, a much better naming convention for triggers would avoid using "random" names.  Following a convention such as naming the trigger the same as the name of the table, followed by _bi, _bu, _bu, _ai, _au, or _ad (for BEFORE/AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) is a more reasonable naming convention.

---

FOLLOWUP

It is possible to perform an `UPDATE` statement in an `AFTER INSERT ON table1` trigger. But... the UPDATE statement cannot modify any rows in `table1`.

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I try to avoid the use of IF statements. Is that possible here?

Comment: Yes, this could be re-written, without an IF statement. e.g. `SET NEW.id = IFNULL(NEW.id,NEW.age);`,  or `SET NEW.id = CASE WHEN NEW.id IS NULL THEN NEW.age ELSE NEW.id END;`

Comment: How would I need to do that? Can you give some tips?

Comment: For the value to be assigned to NEW.id, just use a CASE expression or the return from a function such as IFNULL or COALESCE.  The expression should return the value of NEW.age when NEW.id is null, else, return the value of NEW.id.  (The preference of using this pattern,   to avoid an `IF` statement in a trigger, is very odd.)